# JarURLConnection.connect throwing java.io.FileNotFoundException when URL has "+"

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot

`JarURLConnection.connect` throwing `FileNotFoundException` when JAR file contains `+` char.

> JAR entry BOOT-INF/classes!/sam.wsdl not found in /Users/pp/git/Repo/build/libs/repo-1.1.0+1.jar

**Service Repository:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class SampleService extends Service {

    public SampleService() throws IOException {
        super(new ClassPathResource("sam.wsdl", SampleService.class.getClassLoader()).getURL(), new QName("qname", "serv"));
    }
}
```

This code working perfectly fine when `new ClassPathResource("sam.wsdl", SampleService.class.getClassLoader()).getURL()` resolves to URL

> jar:file:/Users/pp/git/Repo/build/libs/repo-1.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/sam.wsdl

But when I have jar contains `+` throwing FNF exception.

> jar:file:/Users/pp/git/Repo/build/libs/repo-1.1.0+1.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/sam.wsdl

Answer (score 1):

A `+` character in a URL is actually an encoded space (ASCII SP / 0x20) character.

If you want a URL to match a file with `+` in the filename, then the `+` character needs to be percent escaped; e.g.

```
jar:file:/Users/pp/git/Repo/build/libs/repo-1.1.0%2B1.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/sam.wsdl
```